# Is it possible to prevent the Google Play app from creating a shortcut of my App on install?

Tags: android, google-play

When you install an app via Google Play, a shortcut for the app is created on your home screen. The user can prevent this from happening by disabling the "Auto-add Widget" setting within the Google Play app.

From a developer standpoint, I'm wondering if it's possible to prevent this from within my own app. Is there a manifest setting or something else that tells Google not to create an icon for my app on install?

Having no Launcher Activity is not an option for my app.

Answer (score 0):

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-install-uninstall-shortcut-example/
this tutorial is very useful for adding or removing shortcut on homepage

Uninstall Shortcut from Home screen
Similar to install, uninstalling or removing shortcut in Android uses an Intent (UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT) to perform the task. In following code we remove the shortcut added on home screen.

Again we need a permission to perform uninstall shortcut task. Add following permission to Android manifest xml.

```
private void removeShortcut() {

        //Deleting shortcut for MainActivity 
        //on Home screen
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "HelloWorldShortcut");

        addIntent
                .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    }
```